# Postgres index timestamp with timezone column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6, and I have a table named `decks` with an `expiration` column of type `timestamp with time zone` (for storing decks of cards where each card can expire independently).

I'd like to create a nightly cron job that finds all cards which expired at any point during the previous day—i.e. between 0:00 and 23:59 inclusive.

This seems to gives me the time range I want...

```sql
SELECT id
  FROM decks
 WHERE expiration >= (now()::date - 1)::timestamptz
   AND expiration < (now()::date)::timestamptz;
```

...but I'm wondering two things:

1. What's the best way to index the `expiration` column for my scenario?
2. Is there a better/cleaner way to specify the start and end times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: For that query, a standard index is the best option. However, see below.

Question 2: Lots of options, here. A quick change to your query:

```
SELECT id
  FROM decks
WHERE expiration::date = (now()::date - 1);
```

... allows you to create a functional index on `expiration::date` which should be smaller, and a bit more efficient.

Personally, I'd go a bit further and use `current_date` instead of `now()`:

```
SELECT id
  FROM decks
WHERE expiration::date = (current_date - 1);
```

As always, I recommend use of `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` when evaluating indexes.